# use Request.Form command not Request.QueryString command with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

I have simple registration form. Once all information entered, user click submit button and all information sent to default.cs.asp?Process=Add2Member. Everything works. Now, I am trying to implement it into ajax Jquery so that user will stay on same page. I looked at sample codes to do this. I am confused at one point. As I understand, with ajax, I will need to grab data as QueryString but I dont want that. How can I grab it as Request.Form again.

```
    $("[name='signup']").click(function() { 
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "default.cs.asp", 
                success: function(output) { 
                $("#SIGNUPFORM").html(output); 
                //$("#SIGNUPFORM").html(output).append("Üyeliğiniz başarıyla gerçekleşti. Lütfen emailinizi kontrol edin."); 
                },
                error: function(output) {
                $(".SIGNUPFORM").html(output);
                }
                //success: function(msg, textStatus){
                //alert( "Server Response: " + msg );
                //}
            });
```

edit: I made a mistake with type: field. Its GET, not POST.

Comment: Can you post your current html form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the 'type' field 'POST'

Comment: What do you mean? It's up to you, in your ajax callback, as to how to deal with the server response. jQuery will abstract it away so they function the same. POST is what you want to answer your question; you may have another issue in your server-code.

Comment: Right, Request.Form is the correct way to access posted data. I suspect there was some error in the server code when writing the response. What response are you trying to write, and how? Try checking the status of the request in your callback function as well.

Comment: Instead of '$("#SIGNUPFORM").html(output);' write 'alert(output);'. What does it say?

Comment: Right. Okay, so change it so that it is 'function(output, textStatus) { alert(textStatus); }. The problem is, for some reason, your server code is returning nothing.

Comment: But it does return error messages when jquery not used in between. I tried textstatus, success.

Comment: Alright. I think it's the way you're building up your variables for posting then. try form.serialize() instead.

Comment: any samples similar to what I will need? By the way, thank you so much for spending this much time on this.

Comment: Should be: "data : $('form').serialize()"

Comment: so: $("#SIGNUPFORM").serialize();

Comment: and type: "POST"? that simple??

Comment: $("#SIGNUPFORM").serialize(); gives the following error: missing } after property list Source Code: data: $("#SIGNUPFORM").serialize();, ... $("#SIGNUPFORM").serialize() gives no error but no response either.

Comment: It should work mate. At this point I'd take a step back and look for a possibly very simple problem. Sorry I can't help further.

Comment: No worries, and sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have two success methods, and you can only have one.  Second, you need to post your data like data:{firstName:firstname',lastName:'lastname'}, etc.  Since your request is a post you should be able to use request.forms again.  I assume you're using an http handler?

Comment: I am so sorry, type not POST its GET. When I used POST, I could not retrieve server response but GET worked. But then GET is not working with Request.Form